Conexion a una base de datos sqlite3 me da un error
En mi código de conexión a una base de datos en Python con sqlite3, me da un error.
Mi código es:
import sqlite3
con = sqlite.connect(sqlite/app.db)
con.close()

Lo ejecuto y me da el siguiente error:

sqlite3.OperationalError:unable to open database file.

Por favor, si tienen la solución se los agradezco.

Ver la documentación de Python: SQLite3. El primer ejemplo dice como conectarse a una DB de estas, si observas el parámetro es tipo cadena. Esa cadena debe ser la ruta física (absoluta o relativa) donde reside la base de datos, la misma debe tener permisos de lectura y escritura por el usuario del script. Más información.

El código tiene errores: NameError: name 'sqlite' is not defined. Did you mean: 'sqlite3'?

Para que el código te lance un error OperationalError:unable to open database file., se debe asumir que el código de tu archivo es como el que sigue:
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect('sqlite/app.db')
con.close()

(de lo contrario, arrojaría otro tipo de error anunciando que sqlite no está definido)
Asumiendo que el código de tu archivo es como el de arriba, la única forma de que el módulo sqlite3 arroje el error OperationalError:unable to open database file. es que no encuentre la ruta de la base de datos indicada.
Si la ruta 'sqlite/app.db' es correcta, revisa desde qué ruta estás ejecutando tu archivo. Si tu archivo no se encuentra en la misma carpeta en la que se encuentra el directorio sqlite, tendrás que modificar la ruta que le pasas a connect.

Intenta cambiando tu código por este:
import sqlite3
con = sqlite.connect('sqlite/app.db')
con.close()

Me parece que tu error es por que te faltó poner la ruta en una cadena de texto

Esto es más un comentario que una respuesta. Para empezar, el código no compila.
